# Forms module in MSM - change language

Tags: multi-site-manager, devdemon-forms

I created 3 subsites each with different language. Now i find out the same language is loaded for file upload notice "geen bestand".

Where can i change this?

Cant find this string in forms_lang.php

The html the form outputs:

Anyway if im to use forms/language how can i set language for the forms in the subsites?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to look at the language settings in the EE CP. Set the default language to the right one.
what version of EE are you on?

Comment: V2.10.1 Do you mean Default Language in General Configuration? Here is cannot choose anything else then english :s.